# Python Webserver File Output

Tags: python, webserver

I have a Python web-server that is up and running and it will output the file properly to my directory, but I cannot figure out how to either append to the file that is there already or append a timestamp to the file.

The problem is that if the file exists already it will overwrite it instead of making a new file.  So I would like to either:

1. Append the date and timestamp to the file-name OR
2. Just append new data to the existing file.

Also it might be handy to have it automatically detect the server IP Address.

```
import BaseHTTPServer, os, cgi
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import time
import datetime

timeStamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
print timeStamp

class Handler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

def do_GET(self):
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("content-type", "text/html;charset=utf-8")
    self.end_headers()
    self.wfile.write("Upload Complete")

def do_POST(self):

    print self.headers
    form = cgi.FieldStorage(fp = self.rfile)
    ctype, pdict = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('content-type'))
    length = cgi.parse_header(self.headers.getheader('Content-Length'))
    print length[0]
    if ctype == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded':
        qs = self.rfile.read(int(length[0]))
        fout = file(os.path.join('/Inet', 'video.mov'), 'wb')
        fout.write (qs)
        fout.close()
    self.do_GET()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(("192.168.1.10", 8000), Handler)
    print('web server on 8000..')
    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: use `with open(...)` for files and use `'a'` to append.

Comment: I tried that but I cant get the syntax correct for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to append the date and time with this

```
timeStamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A, %d. %B %Y %I-%M%p")
qs = self.rfile.read(int(length[0]))
fout = file(os.path.join('/Inet', 'video_'+timeStamp+'_.mov'), 'wb')
fout.write (qs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing the existing file with 'wb'. Instead you can open the file first with append 'a' and then write to the file.

```
f_path = open(os.path.join('/Inet', 'video.mov'), 'a+')
f_path.write(qs)
```

Comment: I made the change and the file is able to be appended too but, the video is not able to be played and also the second upload request gets a 400 error bad syntax.